# Unable to public Flutter App to Azure App Service - Github Actions

Tags: flutter, azure, github, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.showwcase.com/show/34739/flutter-web-app-to-azure-app-service-with-node-js) for deploying a flutter app to Azure App Service, below is my current workflow, this is created automatically when configuring the deployment centre within the App Service:

```
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - flutter-test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'flutter-test'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_9F371C7309EE423496F3C77A4D2B4CAA }}
          package: .
```

The workflow runs successfully, yet when I navigate to my app service url I see:

[image]

Not what is shown in the tutorial, has anyone done this? I was expecting to see the default flutter starter project.

Answer (score 0):

**This could be because the application is not deployed properly, or any files must be missing.**

1. Check if all the files of application deployed to App Service:

- Go to KUDU site(App Service=>Settings=>Advanced Tools=>Go), click on ***site wwwroot***, check the deployed files:

[image]

[image]
2. Check the logs:

- Go to `web app=>App Service Logs=>Enable application logging` as shown below:

[image]

You can check the logs in **Log Stream**:

[image]

---

I cloned a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/hasnainmakada-99/flutter_web_app_demo) of **Flutter application** by @*hasnainmakada-99* and deployed to Azure web App Service without any issues.

**Steps followed:**

- Created a Linux web app service with Nodejs as run time stack.
- Enable deployment while creating web app.
  In **Deployment** section=>click on **Enable** in **GitHub actions** and provide all the required details:

[image: -]

**Workflow will be created automatically:**

**My workflow:**

```yaml
name: Building and deploying the Node.js application to Azure Web App - <web_app_name>

on:
 push:
   branches:
     - main
 workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
 build:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest

   steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v2

     - name: Set up Node.js version
       uses: actions/setup-node@v1
       with:
         node-version: '18.x'

     - name: npm install, build, and test
       run: |
         npm install
         npm run build --if-present
         npm run test --if-present
     - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
       uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
       with:
         name: node-app
         path: .

 deploy:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   needs: build
   environment:
     name: 'Production'
     url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

   steps:
     - name: Download artifact from build job
       uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
       with:
         name: node-app

     - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
       id: deploy-to-webapp
       uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
       with:
         app-name: '<web_app_name>'
         slot-name: 'Production'
         publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_XXXXXXXXXXX}}
         package: .
```

**Deployment status:**

[image]

Click on the URL which is generated after deployment `https://<web_app_name>.azurewebsites.net`.

**Response:**

[image]